# How to cancel a running Timer() when Widget disappears

Tags: dart, flutter

In a StatefulWidget, I implemented a `deactivate()` method, which does some cleanup.

Actually, the StatefulWidget periodically polls a service and reloads itself with newly received data. Therefore, it uses a `Timer()`, which periodically calls the server polling callback.

The `deactivate()` gets called just fine. But at some deactivations of the widget, the asynchronous `Timer()` still fires a last event and calls the callback - while the widget is partly deactivated.

This is my deactivate():

```
  @protected
  @mustCallSuper
  void deactivate() {

    // allow callback of Timeer() to not execute 
    _timerCanceled = true;

    // Cancel the periodic Timer()
    _timer.cancel();

    // Should be called LAST or FIRST?
    super.deactivate();

  }
```

**Q:General question: How to cancel some asynchronous `Timer()` and ensure, that it doesn't any longer calls the provided callback.**

Or: How to write code that cancels a `Timer()` and execute code after a complete cancel operation, so that the callback of the `Timer()` definitely won't get called.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the Flutter [gallery application example](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/09276bea258737e11b109e227f70eac94a4e1691/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/gallery/app.dart#L42-L146), they use override `dispose` in their `State` class:

```
@override
void dispose() {
  _timeDilationTimer?.cancel();
  super.dispose();
}
```

I am not confident that is correct to create the `Timer` inside the `StatefulWidget`. You might want to refer to the gallery example (and [other examples in the Flutter repository](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/09276bea258737e11b109e227f70eac94a4e1691/examples)).

Comment: I had to explicitly have to test ( null != context ) in a callback to ensure, that context-related code doesn't the yet no longer existing context gets called. Hm...